# C# - Conditionally loading a specific footer w/ a switch statement

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, switch-statement

In my `_Layout.cshtml` file I'm conditionally loading CSS files using a switch statement. If the url includes `collA` or `collD`, then `New.css` loads. If not, then `Old.css` loads. It's working and I'm glad it is.

I want to do the same thing with a `NewFooter` and an `OldFooter`, where if the url includes `collA` then the new one loads, and if not then the old one loads.

But based on the placement of the switch statement, if I conditionally load either footer then they're placed *above* the header. I want the footers to render at the bottom of the page.

Originally I had a second switch statement that conditionally loaded the footers in the right spot, but I only want to work with *one* switch.

Basically, there are three things that I'm trying to achieve:

> 1. I want to conditionally load either `NewFooter` or `OldFooter` using the same switch statement that loads the CSS files
> 2. I want the footers to load at the bottom of the page, rather than above the header
> 3. I only want to use one switch statement

PS - I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and C#, so bear in mind that my syntax is rusty.

---

#### *Layout.cshtml*

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @{
        var keywords = new[] { "colls/collA", "colls/collD" };
        var isNew = RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/NewFooter.cshtml");
        var isOld = RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/OldFooter.cshtml");

        switch (keywords.FirstOrDefault(Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains))
        {
            case "colls/collA":
            case "colls/collD":
                @Styles.Render("~/Content/New.css"); // CSS bundle
                //@isNew; // the issue here is that the NewFooter renders above the header
                break;
            default:
                @Styles.Render("~/Content/Old.css");
                //@isOld;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
// other bundles here

...
...
...

<body>
    @if (!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        // navbar and body code

<div class="body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    // this is where the second switch statement used to be, where the new/old footers were rendered
</div>

...
...
...

</body>
```

Comment: Why one switch?

Comment: Hi @Him, when I had a second switch statement it meant duplicating `case "colls/collA"` and `colls/collD`. The plan is to add more cases (each one represents a page), so having a second switch would mean more work down the line.

Comment: Although I think the whole approach is wrong, you can simply add a flag `bool isNewFooter = false;`, then mark it `true` inside the switch. At the footer, just check if `isNewFooter` is `true` and show the footer accordingly.

Comment: Hey, I followed your instructions and got it to work. If you add your comment as an answer then I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a string `actualURL`, then assign it inside the switch. 
You can render it in the footer (below `@RenderBody()`).